# Loop doesn't give the thumbnail the right parent (or class)

Tags: loop, images, css

I just coded my wp-loop with a custom post type, ready to style it up in my css.

```
<?php $args = array( 'post_type' => 'konzerte', 'category_name' => 'konzert-aktuell' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
            if ( $loop->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
                    echo '<li class=front-layout>';
                        the_title(sprintf('<h3 class="front-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' );    
                        the_excerpt(sprintf('<h4 class="front-excerpt">', '</h4>' ) );
                        the_post_thumbnail('medium', sprintf('<img class="front-thumb">', '</img>'));   
                    echo '</li>';
                endwhile; else: ?>

                <p>Zukünftige Konzerte werden noch nicht beworben.</p>

            <?php endif; ?>
  </div><!-- end .aktuell-front -->
```

Somehow I'm not able to select the img within the list-element or by `.front-thumb`. it works with `img.attachment-medium`, but then I can't let it float left in the list-element.

So the question: How do I select the thumbnail properly in the list?

Comment: read the Codex, 'User Contributed Notes' (the third one - **Styling Post Thumbnails**) in https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_post_thumbnail/

Answer (score -1):

You are incorrectly using `<img` tag..  you'd better use `<div>`:

```
echo '<div class="front-thumb">'.get_the_post_thumbnail('medium').'</div>';
```

p.s. it seems you donk fully understand HTML coding. better to learn the basics.

Comment: I'm totally with you! Learning it right now ;)

But in your exampel you have to cancel the `get`. Otherwise the image does not appear.

But in my browser it stil looks like:
`<li><img src="blabla"><div class=front-thumb"></div></li>`. So the image is outside the `div`. 
Updated loop-part:

`echo '<li>';
the_title(sprintf('<h3 class="front-title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); 
 the_excerpt(sprintf('<h4 class="front-excerpt">', '</h4>' ) );
echo '<div class="front-thumb">'.the_post_thumbnail('medium').'</div>';   
                        echo '</li>':`

Comment: read the Codex https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_post_thumbnail/